GStreamer not loaded in app; works in demo app
I have a Gnome (GJS+GTK4) app where I'm trying to play a video file (local mp4 file). I'm using GTK's video widget, and internally it supposedly uses GStreamer (or is recommended to).
Problem: Video doesn't play; I don't think the media engine (GStreamer) is passing into the app at run-time. How is this done?

Details
While running the app...
The video widget (gtkvideo) seems to load; I see a black box with video controls. However in the center is an "x" icon, indicating an error, and when hovering it I see an error reported:

GTK could not find a media module. Check your installation

Opening the runtime inspector (ctrl+shift+i), in the Global tab, I see "Media engine" is reported as "none". This is a problem! I believe we'd want to see something like "Gstreamer" or "ffmpeg".
In terminal, I see the following...
When running the app, I prepend with GTK_MEDIA=help to get more information:
GTK_MEDIA=help flatpak run org.example.myapp

It reports:

Supported arguments for GTK_MEDIA environment variable:
none - -2147483648

I'd expect to see stuff about GStreamer or FFMPEG here.
Extra notes...
1 - AFAIK, based on this, GTK seems to already take care of GSteamer. Does this work? Can I depend on this? Do I ignore this and should somehow make explicit GStreamer dependencies anyhow?
2 - Assuming the above isn't true or working, I'm attempting to add GStreamer dependencies explicitly, in my root meson.build, however Meson is brand new to me:
gst_ver = '>= 1.20.1'

myapp_deps = [
  dependency('gstreamer-1.0', version: gst_ver),
  dependency('gstreamer-gl-1.0', version: gst_ver),
  dependency('gstreamer-play-1.0', version: gst_ver)
]

These seems to do something during the build procress. Affirming this, if I change the version number wildly I'll see a warning in terminal and build fails. So I know these dependency() lines are doing something.
Dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO found 1.20.7 but need: '>= 9.9.9'
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.27.4)
Run-time dependency gstreamer-1.0 found: NO (tried cmake)

../meson.build:25:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'gstreamer-1.0' ['>= 9.9.9'] found '1.20.7'.

In any case, I would still need to pass dependencies into my (GJS-based) app  somehow. Spinning my wheels on that.
3 - GStreamer, and various related libraries, are installed on my system. Am I missing something still?

libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools
gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3
gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libgtk-4-media-gstreamer

Video works in this app...
The Gnome Workbench demo app has a JS demo that successfully plays video (local mp4 file), and when inspecting the app (ctrl+shift+i), I see "Media engine" as "gstreamer" in the Global tab.
Workbench is doing something that I'm not doing to make GStreamer available to the app. Is it possible Workbench installs an isolated copy of GStreamer just for it's own use? I see a lot of activity in folder build-aux that I don't have in my project.
Workbench code repo: https://github.com/workbenchdev/Workbench
Any help would be appreciated.

I don't know the answer to your question, but you could try entering a shell in Workbench's flatpak container and running your app from there, to see if it works.
